# To create a chess board of same height and width in swift4

Tags: uikit, swift4, stackview

[image]

I am creating this chess game. for building this board i am taking 64 small views and have placed all of them in stack view. but every time i am find that views of one or two rows or columns have not same size as rest of the columns and rows (which have same size views).  For example :- In this image the 2nd and 6th columns  and  2nd and 6th rows have size (67.67 , 67) where all the rest views have size (67, 67) . why this is happening ? How to make all the view with exact same size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of StackView, better to use UICollectionView, as you can then use the FlowLayout of the UICollectionView, and create 64 cells GridView for your chessboard.

I made a GitHub Repo which does that, go to SecondViewController Code: [SourceCode](https://github.com/dep2k/ExpandableStackView)

Explanation:

**Step 1:** Make the collection View width as the multiple of 8 occupying maximum screen width.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let cellWidth = floor(deviceWidth / 8)
    let collectionViewWidth = 8 * cellWidth
    self.collectionViewWidthConstraint.constant = collectionViewWidth

}
```

**Step 2:** Define the size of the collectionCell

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let width = floor(deviceWidth / 8)
    let height = width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

**Step 3:** Define the total number of cells and color of each cell

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return  64
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "unique", for: indexPath)

        let chessRow = indexPath.row / 8
        if chessRow % 2 == 0 {
            if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                 cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }else{
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }
        } else{
            if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }else{
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

**Step 4:** Set the collectionView aspectRatio to 1 in storyboard constraints.

**Final Outcome:** [image: Chessboard]

Comment: Thanks for your responce Deep. can we use gesture recogniser in collection view to move the object from one cell to other cell as like chess game ?

Comment: Yes, you can do. Try to do it, if you face any problem, mention the problem that comes and I will try to check.